# cURL php и GET запрос

Tags: get, php-curl

Хотелось бы понять некоторые ньюансы работы с curl. На одной из вакансий просят создать скрипт для работы с их api. В документации мы инициализируем curl запрос три раза: для авторизации и два раза для сделки. 
**Хочу уточнить, обязательно ли закрывать(curl_close) сеанс после каждого запроса?** Подозреваю это сделано, чтобы в последующем запросе сформировать только нужные параметры. 
Также немного непонятна работа метода GET. Есть параметр "filter/tasks" со значениями "1/2". Если просто написать их как "?filter/tasks=1", то параметр не воспринимается, нужно указывать его как "?filter[tasks]=1". **Как это работает и где об этом можно подробнее узнать?**

Comment: про get запросы гугл много знает.. а касательно соединения - можно не закрывать его (по завершении работы все ресурсы автоматически закрываются и больше не доступны), если вам надо выполнить несколько последовательных запросов.

Comment: google это хорошо, но ничего кроме как "/" относится к спецсимволам url я не нашел. Поэтому вывод, что filter/tasks должен также работать. 
Появился еще вопрос об curl_init() и сброс параметров. Если каждый запрос инициализировать соединение не закрывая старое, то параметры сбрасываются? Или можно одно открытое соединение использовать на все запросы?

Comment: Ну, я про "/" и сам не знаю почему не обрабатывает, знаю что если в значении он то с ним парсится всё.. Насчет соединения - если не закрывать и для запросов заново инициализировать то параметры сбрасываются, можно не закрывая канал сделать несколько запросов.. Но тут ещё зависит от времени ожидания "запроса" на сервере, если долго ждать он может разорвать соединение